# jQuery File Upload: size of the original image

Tags: jquery, performance, resize, size, image-resizing

I'm using jQuery File Upload to save:

```
Original file;
Big;
Medium;
Thumb;
```

Now I send 50 images and the originals are 85% of folder size.

The original is saving image as 1280px, how I change it to 800x800?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is change the:
imageMaxWidth and imageMaxHeight parameters. Full example:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        paramName: 'files[]',
        autoUpload: true,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 999000,
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        //previewMaxWidth: 100,
        //previewMaxHeight: 100,
        imageMaxWidth: 800,
        imageMaxHeight: 800,
        imageCrop: false,
        previewCrop: true
    });
```